# Swarm Networking and Spring Cloud Apps

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-compose, spring-cloud, docker-swarm

I’m doing some investigation into docker 1.13 & swarm.

We use Spring Boot Microservices with Eureka for service discovery of the services.

I’m having problems with getting our services to see each other. Some of the services start on the ingress network, and others on the network I created for the stack. It’s pretty confusing and I’m not entirely sure if it’s an issue that I’ve created in docker stack setup or how I define my service definition in Eureka. I’ve created a much smaller microservice system that reproduces the steps I followed and I wondered if someone could take a look to see if I’m missing something from my network definition or service definition in the compose file:

https://github.com/KramKroc/nonzeroexit

Comment: Quick take: Setting hostname seems unnecessary since you're using the same name as the service, service discovery should take care of it. Can you provide more info on how you're running this? Are you creating a swarm and running `docker stack depoly -c docker-compose.yml`? What's the errors that you're seeing?

Comment: You need to provide the addressable hostname or ip to eureka specifically rather than relying on the guess of spring cloud.

Comment: Hi @ManoMarks the github repo contains details of the steps I took to start the swarm.

Comment: @spencergibb I ended up using the --subnet switch:

    docker network create -d overlay --subnet 10.10.0.0/24 demo-network

And then via config I set the preferredNetwork:
    spring: 
        cloud:
            inetutils:
                preferredNetworks:
                    - ${preferred.network.front:10.10.0}

And that has solved a lot of my issues.